# "(...) afford stuff for a good joke to anybody, (...)" - what does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, uncountable-nouns

I'm not sure what does Melville exactly mean by ***afford stuff for a good joke to anybody*** in chapter five of [Moby-Dick](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701).

> However, a good laugh is a mighty good thing, and rather too scarce a good thing; the more’s the pity. So, if any one man, in his own proper person, ***afford stuff for a good joke to anybody***, let him not be backward, but let him cheerfully allow himself to spend and be spent in that way.

From the research I did and the context of the passage methought, can it be [***money***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stuff#Noun)? How would you rephrase it without using ***stuff***?

Comment: *Stuff* → *things*. It would make no sense for it to mean money. (Afford money?)

Answer (score 1):

- So, if any one man, in his own proper person, afford stuff for a good joke to anybody . . . let him cheerfully allow himself to spend and be spent in that way.*

afford stuff for = provide the material for

to spend and be spent = to be used